# Difficulty reaching lower E to higher G in left hand on piano

Tags: piano, fingering

I’m practising the below piano piece and can’t physically keep one finger on lower E and higher G at the same time (circles in picture). I think I must have the notes wrong or not reading the music correctly and missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: who could? only a few of us! But don't worry about this.  (With a sustain pedal this would be no problem of course!) You can play E e g e by 5 1 2 1 and hold the E only a half note. It will be still present in your ear - there are still 2 E in 2 octaves. hold the upper E a half note.

Answer (score 2):

This is an arrangement of a pop song. Nobody bothers about the correct interpretation of such an arrangement. You can accompany with the sustain pedal. The left hand chords can be held as long you want, take care with the passing tones in the right hand (f# bar 2, f# and d bar 3 etc).

In a classical piece you have to be more correct.

But then you could apply a sostenuto pedal:

> On a modern grand piano with three pedals, the middle pedal is usually a sostenuto pedal. It sustains only those notes that are being held down when the pedal is depressed, allowing future notes played to be unaffected. It is commonly abbreviated "S.P.", "Sost. Ped.", or "ThP." (from the German equivalent "Tonhalte-Pedal").

> On some upright pianos and lower-quality grand pianos, the middle pedal sustains all notes in the bass register, but this is not a true sostenuto pedal. On other uprights, the middle pedal is a practice pedal (with a locking option), which makes the sound extremely quiet beyond the standard soft pedal. This is often achieved by dropping a felt cloth between the hammers and the strings when the practice pedal is depressed. Not all pianos have a sostenuto pedal, however. Some older, or modern low-quality uprights do not have this option.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sostenuto

Comment: Feels a bit dismissive; it's not at all uncommon for some notes being given overly long durations, even in the most high-brow music.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My advice is referring to this 6 bars. What do you mean by high- brows?

Comment: With high-brow I meant music that is considered proper art, aka classical. You implied that the rules are different because this is pop music, whereas this notation is also common for music written by the great masters of old - see the Rachmaninoff example from my answer.

Comment: yes, but OP doesn't ask about Rachmaninoff, I couldn't play Rachmaninoff not after 60 years practice without a sostenuto pedal.

Comment: I think a proper sustain pedal works well enough too. The notation of a low note lasting much longer is really common - surely not everyone needs special pianos to accompany those works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not always have to take notation literally; particularly note durations. When there are multiple voices in the left hand, it is common for one note or chord in the lower register to be given a very long duration, while shorter notes are proscribed in a higher register - often an octave or further apart. See this example from Rachmaninoff's Prelude in C# Minor:

[image: Rachmaninoff example]

He even does it with both hands; holding the low C#'s in the second measure far into the third. Try holding those octaves whilst performing the eighth-note chords; you would need four hands!

It is more about the impression of those low notes sounding for that duration; which you can do by playing them a little louder, and holding the sustain pedal for the duration. That works only if the higher notes are not staccato, which prohibits pedal. In your case, pedal would work fine.

Another example, this one from Liszt's Reminiscences de Norma:

[image: Liszt example]

Comment: This is a classical piece supposed to perform on a grand piano with a sostenuto pedal, yes?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Yes; it was written by Rachmaninoff for piano.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Oh wait, I forgot about sostenuto. I do not think that he specified that pedal.

Comment: yes, but this is a quite different situation: Both hands are articulating a expressive motive. OP's example shows a simple arpeggio. A similar accentuation would be displaced here. The accompaniment is supposed to be calm and flowing.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Well, in that case I will acknowledge that I do not know it for sure. I feel like a regular sustain pedal should suffice, both for the old pieces and the new. That is what I hear when I listen to performances of the Rachmaninoff.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli I added another example where the low notes are not accented

Comment: No problem. I don't have one. I would try to play the Rachmaninoff bars like you explain. But not this piece of OP is questioning about.

Comment: OK, the Liszt piece certainly affords a sostenuto pedal, the left hand is occupied the whole bar.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Right; I just thought that for such a notation, the sustain pedal would be acceptable too. But, I do not know for sure.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Those of us who haven't got sostenuto pedals *have* to use the sustain. But then the three ensuing chords *also* get sustained, which isn't precisely what Rachmaninoff  wanted.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I get that now, but listening to [this recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOx710drHnw) I am positive the performer is using the sustain. The first and second chord flow into one another a bit too smoothly. The third chord is separate, for it would be dissonant with the first two, but then the C#'s abruptly stop sounding as well.

Comment: The sostenuto pedal was not common in pianos in Liszt's time.